# Cloud Functions Update Sub-collections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a cloud function to trigger every time a product on my project gets updated. Here is the idea.

I have 2 collections, **stores** and **products**.

Inside the **stores** collection, there is a sub-collection called **products** that contains all the products that the store sells. The data 'gets fed' by copying specific items from the main **products** root collection
The idea is the my project gets a good performance as well as cost effective.

In order for this to work, I need to create a cloud function to be triggered every time a product gets modified and query all the **stores** that has that same *product id* and update the data.

I'm having a really hard time with that. Can anybody shine a light here for me? This is my cloud function.

```
// Exporting the function
export const onProductChange = functions.firestore
.document('products/{productId}')
// Call the update method
.onUpdate(async (snap, context) => {
    // Get the product ID
    const productID = context.params.productID;
    // Query for all the collections with the specific product ID.
    const resultSnapshot = await db.collectionGroup('products')
        .where('id', '==', productID).get();

    // Filter for the collections with the 'products' root and return an array.
    const snaphotsInStoreSubcollection = resultSnapshot.docs.filter(
        (snapshot: any) => {
            return snapshot.ref.parent === 'products';
    });

    const batch = db.batch();
    // Takes each product and update
    snaphotsInStoreSubcollection.forEach((el: any) => {
        batch.set(el.ref, snaphotsInStoreSubcollection.product);
    });
    await batch.commit();
});
```

---

error on cloud function console

> Error: Value for argument "value" is not a valid query constraint. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value. at Object.validateUserInput (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:273:15) at validateQueryValue (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1844:18) at Query.where (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:956:9) at exports.onProductChange.functions.firestore.document.onUpdate (/srv/lib/product-update.js:29:10) at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23) at /worker/worker.js:825:24 at  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: onWrite might be preferred if users can add new products and they also need to be copied. Also, you should be returning your batch.commit(). More info is needed on the errors. Also, what does it say in your 'functions' log?

Comment: Hey guys sorry about that. i've added the error log.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a look at this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions) and specially in [Event Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions#event_triggers).

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `snapshotsInStoreSubcollection.product` is undefined

`batch.set(el.ref, snaphotsInStoreSubcollection.product);`

A snapshot is a document and its data is `snapshot.data()`

You cannot set `undefined` as a value in firestore and you are attempting to